# How can I drag a file to a <div> and have it submit to a file field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you drag a file to a file field button (the one that says "Choose File") it automatically selects that file for the field. Is there anyway that I could drag a file to a `<div>` and execute the same action so that the file would be attached to the file field as if I had dragged it directly to the file field?

Comment: Have you tried setting the file field button to `opacity: 0` and placing it on top of the div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting the `opacity: 0` as suggested by R. Schifini and `position: absolute` I was able to create a div with an invisible file field on top of it. So, when the user clicked on the div they could select a file to use or the could drag their file to the div and select a file that way.